# Magento2 AWS Credentials error

Tags: magento2

I have installed following extension.

> https://github.com/thaiphan/magento2-s3/wiki/Installation

While trying to upload the images using export cmd, getting below error

```
The AWS credentials you provided did not work. Please review your details and try again. You can do so using our config script.
```